# Error calling Microsoft Graph API authentication/phoneMethods - 'Unexpected segment OpenPropertySegment. Expected property/$value'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to register a 2FA method for a user on signup for my FooBar application.
I can create the user, I can update the user's information with no problems.

The API I am trying to POST to is documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/phoneauthenticationmethod?view=graph-rest-beta

I am using this:

```
//Create basic JSON for the request
var jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
jsonBuilder.Append("{");
jsonBuilder.Append($"\"phoneType\": \"mobile\",");
jsonBuilder.Append($"\"phoneNumber\": \"{phone}\"");
jsonBuilder.Append("}");
var json = jsonBuilder.ToString();

// Get Access token
var accessToken = await GetAccessToken(settings);

// Create the URL
var http = new HttpClient();
var url = "https://graph.windows.net/[tenant guid]/users/[user id]/authentication/phoneMethods?api-version=1.6";

// Create the request
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

//Wait for response and content to be returned
var response = await http.SendAsync(request);
```

The response is

```
{\"lang\":\"en\",\"value\":\"Unexpected segment OpenPropertySegment. Expected property/$value.\"}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: (any reason you're rolling your own JSON instead of using an existing implementation?)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann none really, I just picked this up from samples and it became how I was using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var phoneAuthenticationMethod = new PhoneAuthenticationMethod
{
    PhoneNumber = "+1 2065555554",
    PhoneType = AuthenticationPhoneType.Mobile
};

await graphClient.Me.Authentication.PhoneMethods["{phoneAuthenticationMethod-id}"]
    .Request()
    .PutAsync(phoneAuthenticationMethod);
```

Thanks

Comment: I assume GraphServiceClient is coming from a nuget package? Can you share which one you used?

Comment: For V1 - To install the client library via NuGet:

Search for Microsoft.Graph in the NuGet Library, or
Type Install-Package Microsoft.Graph into the Package Manager Console

Comment: Refer documentation here - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet#microsoft-graph-net-client-library